# Jmeter - WebDriver Sampler

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I need to wait for an element to disappear from the screen. I know how to wait for an element to be visible, I used the code below:

`wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("mainLoadingDialog")))`

Now I just need to do the opposite and wait until the element is not visible anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementLocated.htm):

```
 until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(pkg.By.xpath("mainLoadingDialog")));
```

> An expectation for checking that an element is either invisible or not present on the DOM.